# Getting a string value from vector of vectors

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Given this data structure

```
(def file-types 
 [["figure" "Figure"]
  ["video" "Video"]
  ["graphic" "Inline Graphic/Custom Artwork"]
  ["other" "Other"]])
```

Given this "key"

```
(def file-type "graphic")
```

This there a better way of getting the second value from the corresponding tuple?

```
(defn get-file-label [file-types file-type]
  (second (peek (filterv #(= (% 0) file-type) file-types))))
```

Expected output `"Inline Graphic/Custom Artwork"`

Answer (score 3):

Easy peasy!  Just convert the sequence of string pairs into a map for fast lookup:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(dotest
  (let [file-types [["figure" "Figure"]
                    ["video" "Video"]
                    ["graphic" "Inline Graphic/Custom Artwork"]
                    ["other" "Other"]]
        file->type (into {} file-types)]
    (is= (file->type "graphic") "Inline Graphic/Custom Artwork")))
```

Be sure to review the [Clojure CheatSheet](http://clojure.org/cheatsheet) and [this list](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation) of other docs.

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes a lot of sense